# Присваивание результата запроса MS SQL 2005

Tags: переменные, sql-server, select

**Добрый день.**

Требуется присвоить переменной А (тип int) результат запроса (тоже int)

Код:

```
DECLARE @A  int;
Set @A = 
SELECT ДокументПоступлениеТоваровИДН FROM ДокументПоступлениеТоваров WHERE
Дата = '05.05.2005 0:00:00' 
AND Склад = 'Склад'
AND Поставщик = 'Поставщик'
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого
> слова "SELECT"

в третьей строке. Как ни пробовал, не получается :( Сам запрос (!) выполняется правильно, мне кажется  что-то нужно дописать где-то в раене присваивания, но вот  что именно:(

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выйти из ситуаци. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @A = ДокументПоступлениеТоваровИДН FROM ДокументПоступлениеТоваров WHERE
Дата = '05.05.2005 0:00:00' 
AND Склад = 'Склад'
AND Поставщик = 'Поставщик'
```

Comment: работает. спасибо)